# Asian High School Drama with arrogant boy and poor girl

Tags: identify-this-movie

This is what I remember so far:

- Asian drama (prob. Korean)
- High school involved
- Released: About early 2000s
- Very rich and arrogant boy and a sick poor girl and some kind of inheritance involved
- I remember a touching scene on a swing.

I remember that the arrogant boy slowly loses his temper and falls in love with the girl. The boy cannot have his inheritance because of some rules about living in countryside or something. They get married but girl dies at the end because of the sickness.

The boy is good looking and tall; and girl is tiny and I guess works in about every place in the village from school to cafe.

Comment: There is nothing much to go forward, can you provide more detail like some story point, how does character look etc etc.

Comment: Add those details in question itself by edit button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you're looking for the korean movie [a millionaire's first love](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0757157/)

> Jae-Kyung (Hyun-Bin ) is a high school senior, who skips school often.
>   Once he turns nineteen years old, he is going to be a millionaire.
>   However, the day before he is set to inherit his fortune, their family
>   lawyer informs Jae-Kyung about the will from his deceased grandfather.
>   His grandfather specified that Jae-Kyung can only inherit his fortune
>   if he graduates from Boram High School, which is located in the
>   countryside. He has no choice but to transfer there.
>
> Life changes a lot for him at Boram High School. He can't use his
>   credit card or drive his sports car. Meanwhile, Jae-Kyung meets
>   Eun-Hwan (Lee Yeon-Hee). She's different from the other people living
>   there and seems to harbor some kind of secret. Jae-Kyung's attitude
>   begins to change and Eun-Hwan is about to reveal her secret.

Movie is available in youtube as well

Comment: Sounds promising but can you add in the relevant section of the plot summary to make this more of a complete answer?